# TextFormField with only red border on validation

Tags: flutter, forms, validation, padding, textformfield

I'm trying to create a TextFormField that, in case of validation error, only has a red border, and that is happening. But, there is a strange behavior, when the field validation error occurs, the field moves up.

I believe this is caused by the "contentPadding" property that I added, without it, the field does not move, but it ends up resizing its height, and I don't want that to happen, I want everything to remain fixed with their sizes and where they are positioned, only with the red border in case of error.

Here is the code for my TextFormField:

```
import 'package:beatscore/app/utils/beatscore_colors.dart';
import 'package:beatscore/main.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

// ignore: must_be_immutable
class CustomTextField extends StatelessWidget {
  CustomTextField(
      {super.key,
      required this.onMutted,
      this.placeholder,
      this.protected = false,
      this.prefixIcon,
      this.suffixIcon,
      this.suffixAction,
      this.inputFormatters,
      this.validator,
      this.controller,
      this.textInputType,
      this.errorText});

  Icon? prefixIcon;
  Icon? suffixIcon;
  bool protected;
  Function()? suffixAction;
  Function onMutted;
  String? placeholder;
  TextEditingController? controller;
  String? Function(String)? validator;
  List<TextInputFormatter>? inputFormatters;
  TextInputType? textInputType;
  String? errorText;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        horizontal: 16,
        vertical: 8,
      ),
      child: SizedBox(
        width: 310,
        child: TextFormField(
          keyboardType: textInputType,
          autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
          validator: validator == null ? null : (value) => validator!(value!),
          inputFormatters: inputFormatters,
          onChanged: (value) => onMutted(value),
          cursorColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0),
          style: const TextStyle(
              fontSize: 16,
              color: Color.fromRGBO(30, 30, 30, 0.6),
              height: 1.6),
          obscureText: protected,
          controller: controller,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            errorBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: BeatscoreColors.ligthErrorRed),
            ),
            contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              horizontal: 12.5,
              vertical: 12.5,
            ),
            errorText: errorText,
            hintText: placeholder,
            prefixIcon: prefixIcon,
            suffixIcon: suffixIcon != null
                ? IconButton(
                    icon: suffixIcon!,
                    onPressed: suffixAction,
                  )
                : null,
            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                borderSide: const BorderSide(
                  width: 0,
                  style: BorderStyle.none,
                )),
            filled: true,
            fillColor: Colors.white,
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
              borderSide: const BorderSide(
                width: 0,
                style: BorderStyle.none,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

A gif to show what is happening:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that you are most probably returning an empty (or containing some other whitespace) string from the `validator` callback. Flutter then paints this `errorText` (or just text's strut if it's empty) with an additional gap between the text and the input itself.

---

[image: dartpad screenshot explaining how empty string takes space too]

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: const [
            TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(errorText: 'Some error'),
            ),
            TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(errorText: ''),
            ),
            TextField(),
          ]
              .map(
                (w) => Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.1),
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue),
                  ),
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(32),
                  child: w,
                ),
              )
              .toList(),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's what happens, it was an attempt to "disable" the error message and only show the red border. But this weird behavior occurs, I don't want an error message or anything like that, just the red border. I can't come up with a solution.

Comment: You can simply change the border color in `InputDecoration.enabledBorder` and `.focusedBorder` and refrain from using `validator`, as having this error text is something that Material's `TextField` relies on. You can see it inside the `input_decorator.dart` in `_HelperError` widget.